# Java EE .jsp file can't be accessed through localhost

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, wildfly

So, I tried to run a jsp page for the first time on Eclipse Java EE, and the localhost cannot access it.
The localhost is able to access any html page, but not jsp pages. I'm attaching the error displayed on the console, it says something about an invalid character on a cookie, but I cleaned everything.
I even reinstalled Eclipse, Java, JBoss and WildFly.
I've been trying to solve this for 7 hours now, none of my co-workers was able to find the solution.
The weirdest thing is that a colleague of mine is having exactly the same issue, but we can't find helpful answers online. Our computers are totally different though, so we can't understand the connection.

```html
Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /tutorial1/submit.jsp request {Connection=[keep-alive], Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8], Accept-Language=[pt-PT,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4], Cache-Control=[max-age=0], Accept-Encoding=[gzip, deflate, sdch], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response {Connection=[keep-alive], X-Powered-By=[Undertow/1, JSP/2.3], Server=[WildFly/11], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1], Content-Length=[482], Date=[Tue, 30 Jan 2018 17:22:04 GMT]}}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [181] was present in the cookie value or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupport.java:142)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.java:163)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCookieSupport.java:248)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:154)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(HttpResponseConduit.java:161)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpResponseConduit.java:596)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal(HttpServerExchange.java:2042)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:603)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriter.close(ServletPrintWriter.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletPrintWriterDelegate.close(ServletPrintWriterDelegate.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:473)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:339)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: *UT000173: An invalid control character [181] was present in the cookie value or attribute* - Clear browser cookies.

Comment: I already did that @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Then edit your code that sets cookie values, and clear them again.

Comment: You might also try another browser, though unlikely to help if you are dealing with anything cookie related in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, it was because of Wildfly 11. I downgraded it to Wildfly 10.1 and it started working!